# python ndb classes that reference each other

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have two classes:

```
class A(ndb.Model):
    first_prop = ndb.StructuredProperty(B)

class B(ndb.Model):
    second_prop = ndb.StructuredProperty(A)
```

putting the class name in quotes gives an error.

What is a reasonable way to make it happen , which leaves code encapsulation intact ?

Comment: Have you thought this through, I doubt this could work, you have effectively created a recursive property.

Comment: Hmmm ... This seems like it could lead to problems with cyclical references which I'd be shocked if the datastore handled that...

Comment: what are you attempting to achieve?

Comment: You want each A to fully **contain** a B which fully **contains** an A which fully **contains** a B (etc ad infinitum)?!  How can that possibly make any sense?  One of the two can be a `StructuredProperty`, but the other one had better be a `KeyProperty` which only **references** the other kind rather than **containing** an entity of that kind (and if you want to constrain the kind, you can use the string name with `KeyProperty` -- where it may make sense -- though not with `StructuredProperty` -- where it makes no sense).

Comment: this example is just to illustrate the problem. it's perfectly acceptable to have an instance of `A` with `first_prop = an empty instance of B` , it will not lead to an infinite loop.

Comment: But what is the point of having a property that you will never populate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign a property **after** the models were defined. See `_fix_up_properties` doc strings [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/googleappengine/python/+/24a47c532460d92438b3a42347dd83862a7ed4c8/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py#3081).

```
class A(ndb.Model):
  pass

class B(ndb.Model):
  pass

A.first_prop = ndb.StructuredProperty(B)
B.second_prop = ndb.StructuredProperty(A)
A._fix_up_properties()
B._fix_up_properties()
```

Comment: Let us know if this approach will create a black hole in the datastore or not.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use `ndb.KeyProperty` instead of `ndb.StructuredProperty`.  Using the former, it is perfectly acceptable to have two classes reference each other.

Comment: this example is an alias to another more concrete real world problem. I am using `endpoints proto datastore` and I need to make `@EndpointsAliasProperty(property_type=B.ProtoModel())` ,

refering to each class in the annotaion of a function.

Comment: @user47376, then ask a question about the real-world problem instead of the one you asked...